# How to expose relations of an embedded id in a join table as links with Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

**Intro**

Let's say in a Spring Boot application with the Spring Data Rest module there are two main entities (e. g. `Student` and `LegalGuardian`). They are joined via an "association entity" (e. g. `Guardianship`) that is identified by an embedded id (e. g. `GuardianshipId`). Further, this embedded id consists of relations to the two main entities (not the id's of the main entities - the entities themself).

```
// The Main entities

@Entity
public class Student extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

  private String name;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "guardianshipId.student")
  private List<Guardianship> guardianships;
  
  // getters and setters
  
}

@Entity
public class LegalGuardian extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

  private String name;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "guardianshipId.legalGuardian")
  private List<Guardianship> guardianships;
  
  // getters and setters
  
}

// The association entity

@Entity
public class Guardianship implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private GuardianshipId guardianshipId;
  
  private String name;
  
  // getters, setters, equals and hashCode

  @Embeddable
  public static class GuardianshipId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private LegalGuardian legalGuardian;
    
    // getters, setters, equals and hashCode

  }

}
```

For all those entities there exists separate repositories:

- `StudentRepository : JpaRepository<Student, Long>`,
- `LegalGuardianRepository : JpaRepository<LegalGuardian, Long>` and
- `GuardianshipRepository : JpaRepository<Guardianship, Guardianship.GuardianshipId>`

To query single `Guardianship`s of `GuardianshipRepository` by id via REST, also a `BackendIdConverter` is implemented (so that the id then looks like *{studentId}_{legalGuardianId}*).

If the repository of the association entity is requested, by default the embedded id itself (and its attributes) is not serialized, so that the response looks like this:

```
$ curl "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
{
  "name" : "Cool father",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
    },
    "guardianship" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
    }
  }
}
```

**Quesion/Problem**

What has to be done, so that response includes **links** to the entities that are defined inside the embedded id and looks like this:

```
$ curl "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
{
  "name" : "Cool father",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
    },
    "guardianship" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
    },
    "student" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2/student"
    },
    "legalGuardian" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2/legalGuardian"
    }
  }
}
```

**(Naive and successless) Attempt/Try**

The first thought was to make the nested relations accessible by delegating to the embedded id:

```
@Entity
public class Guardianship implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private GuardianshipId guardianshipId;
  
  public Student getStudent() { return guardianshipId.getStudent(); }
  
  public LegalGuardian getLegalGuardian() { return guardianshipId.getLegalGuardian(); }
  
  // the same as before

}
```

But doing this, both entities are completely serialized and the response looks like this:

```
$ curl "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
{
  "name" : "Cool father",
  "student" : {
    "name" : "Hans",
    "new" : false
  },
  "legalGuardian" : {
    "name" : "Peter",
    "new" : false
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
    },
    "guardianship" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
    }
  }
}
```

For a full example, I created an executable [sample project](https://gitlab.com/hjoeren/sdrjteid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I found two possible ways to expose the ID relations as links:

**1. Providing a [`RepresentationModelProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/server/RepresentationModelProcessor.html)**

Implementing `RepresentationModelProcessor` lets me add custom links to the response representation.

```
@Component
public class GuardianshipProcessor
    implements RepresentationModelProcessor<EntityModel<Guardianship>> {

  @Autowired
  private RepositoryEntityLinks repositoryEntityLinks;

  @Override
  public EntityModel<Guardianship> process(EntityModel<Guardianship> model) {
    Link studentLink = repositoryEntityLinks.linkToItemResource(Student.class,
        model.getContent().getGuardianshipId().getStudent().getId());
    model.add(studentLink);
    Link legalGuardianLink = repositoryEntityLinks.linkToItemResource(LegalGuardian.class,
        model.getContent().getGuardianshipId().getLegalGuardian().getId());
    model.add(legalGuardianLink);
    return model;
  }

}
```

```
$ curl "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
{
  "name" : "Cool father",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
    },
    "guardianship" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
    },
    "student" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/students/1"
    },
    "legalGuardian" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/legalGuardians/2"
    }
  }
}
```

*Pro:*

- matches the desired response representation exactly

*Con:*

- more association classes leads to more implementations of `RepresentationModelProcessor` doing more or less the same

**2. Configure the [`RepositoryRestConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.html) to expose ID's**

By default, ID's are not exposed by Spring Data Rest and although the topic is about embedded id's, these are also ID's. This behavior is configurable class by class.

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.exposeIdsFor(Guardianship.class);
  }
  
}
```

```
$ curl "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
{
  "guardianshipId" : {
    "_links" : {
      "student" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/students/1"
      },
      "legalGuardian" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/legalGuardians/2"
      }
    }
  },
  "name" : "Cool father",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
    },
    "guardianship" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/guardianships/1_2"
    }
  }
}
```

*Pro:*

- less "implementation"

*Con:*

- (in this form) does not match the original desired response representation exactly (see the `guardianshipId`-wrapper around the links)

---

**Edit**

For the way two: To expose all ID's for entities, that are using embedded (composite) ids something like the following is possible:

```
@Configuration                                                                                
public class RepositoryRestConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {                       
                                                                                              
  @Autowired                                                                                  
  Repositories repositories;                                                                  
                                                                                              
  @Override                                                                                   
  public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {      
    repositories.forEach(repository -> {                                                      
      Field embeddedIdField =                                                                 
          ReflectionUtils.findField(repository, new AnnotationFieldFilter(EmbeddedId.class)); 
      if (embeddedIdField != null) {                                                          
        config.exposeIdsFor(repository);                                                      
      }                                                                                       
    });                                                                                       
  }                                                                                           
                                                                                              
}
```